# Unable to return correct query when using string parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a simple employee table

[image: employee table]

and here is the data

[image: employee table data]

When I try to run a query with string parameter it doesn't return anything although it has correct parameter

[image: query with correct string parameter]

and when I try to change it to double quote ", it returns an error

[image: query enclosed parameter with "" for string parameters]

Have I missed something? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your first query is the good one. Everything seem good, but you have to make several tries to ensure everything is in place. Are you querying the same server and database ? What happens if you query "select * from Employee" ? And if you Query "select 'x' + empId + 'x', * from Employee" ?

Comment: when i try to run just select * from employee it runs perfectly, and when i try to run query with int parameters like status, it return a correct query

Comment: Try to run select * from Employee where empId like '%10002%' . The first query seems to be ok...

Comment: If `Empid` is the **numerical** employee id - ***why*** isn't this stored as a **numerical** datatype?!?!?!?!? It should be - then you won't have any of those messy "extra space at the end" and so forth problems when you abuse a `varchar` to store a number !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query is correct.  The problem is the data.  The `empid` field has something other than `'10002'` in the field.  You can investigate this in various ways:

```
select length(empid), '|' + empid + '|'
from employee
```

This will provide information about unexpected characters that you might not see.  The length for the field should be 6.  The output for the second column should be "|100002|".

If an extra character at the beginning or end of the field is the issue, then:

```
where empid = '%100002%'
```

solves the problem.  However, there is a big potential performance difference, because this query cannot take advantage of the primary key index.  So, you want to fix the data.

You might have confused the letter zero with the number, or capital "I" or lower case "l" for 1.  These can be harder to spot, but you can use `lower()` and `upper()` to help find such issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a special char, like a carriage return, at the end of the value.
Use the query below to check if there are some of those cases in your table.

```
    SELECT
       EmpId,
    --   convert(int, EmpId) AS EmpId_INT,
       LEN(EmpId) AS Len_EmpId
    FROM
       Employee
    -- WHERE
    --   LEN(EmpId) <> LEN(convert(int, EmpId))
    ORDER BY
       EmpId
```

If it's not mandatory, I suggest to change the "EmpId" data type to int.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the data type of the empId column to Int instead of varchar.